# fancybox 2.1.4 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox, fancybox-2

Having some issues with a website that I am working on I can't seem to get fancybox to work correctly testing it with a YouTube clip.

Here is my script file.
Using 2.1.4 with jQuery 1.9

script.js

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

    $j('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });

    $j('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });

});
```

the flexslider works just fine however the fancybox-media is having issues.
when i click the link it just opens the link instead of opening media file in a fancybox window.

Inside the chrome console it is saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined jquery.fancybox-media.js:88
(anonymous function) jquery.fancybox-media.js:88
(anonymous function) jquery.fancybox-media.js:196
```

The link is defined as:

```
<h2><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czQipWJA8EU">Watch This Video</a></h2>
```

Also if you want to look at the site in development
it can be found at www.miems.co

Any ideas please let me know.
Sincerely,
David

Comment: Well after playing around i said heck with it and ended up fixing it by dropping back to jquery-1.8.0.min.js and rolling back to fancybox 2.0 instead of using media frame i decided to go with the old iframe setup so using this now.

Comment: Your fancybox code works just fine with jQuery v1.9.1, check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E6PYz/1/)** ... are you sure you didn't forget to include the jquery.fancybox-media.js file?

Answer (score 10):

Given that there are hundreds of views and no answer yet

The

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

needs to be called before calling any other code from fancybox

In my case I had change the order in which javascript gets executed, 
from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same error because I had foolishly included the jquery.fancybox.js twice on the page. Just remove the second call, and the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress,
After long research and updates:

having had the theme loaded with Fancybox and in addition to this I had a plugin also using fancybox,
**This created a double call to Fancybox**.
Ashish Kumar pointed that out. Thank you
I only disabled the plugin and all errors disappeared.

Theme: tourpackage

Plugin: Easy Fancybox